# Angular 8 jsonp Callback not invoked

Tags: javascript, http, jsonp, angular8

I'm using Angular 8 and the HttpClientJsonpModule. Here's my custom fetch function:

```
public fetch(): Observable<any> {
    // This url has been obfuscated but you get the gist. This is the expected format so I can't alter the string
    const url = 'http://exampleurl:6000/GetSomeData(inputParams=@test1)?@test1={hasData=true}';

    return this.http.jsonp(url, 'callback')
        .pipe(
            map(response => {
               // always returns null
               console.log(response);
            })
        );
}
```

When I call `this.fetch()` the following error always returns:

> JSONP injected script did not invoke callback.

And `response` is always null.  Am I missing a step somewhere?

Comment: Does the URL really return JSONP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't provide the callback in your request. In the following sample, the query parameter to provide the callback is c (it actually depends on the service). You always need to provide the JSONP_CALLBACK value for such parameter.

const url = 'http://exampleurl:6000/GetSomeData(inputParams=@test1)?callback=JSONP_CALLBACK&@test1={hasData=true}';